# Updating a column with newly inserted data after insert trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have an "`Employee`" table that has columns called '`E#`' and "`TOTAL_BUDGET`".

I have a "`WorkOn`" table that display all `P#` that employees are working on.

I have a "`Project`" table that has columns called '`Budget`', `'E#'` and '`P#`'.

What i want to do is that whenever a new project is **assigned** to an employee (e.g new data inserted into WorkOn), a row trigger will **update** the **TOTAL_BUDGET** column with budgets of **all projects** that the employee is assigned to.

For example, if **employee 1** is currently assigned to project **1,2,3** with budget **10K, 15K and 5K** respectively, after inserting a new project **4** with budget of **5K** for employee **1** into **WorkOn** table, row trigger will update **TOTAL_BUDGET** for employee **1** to **35K**.

However, what my row trigger currently does is that it is always excluding the newly assigned project budget before updating the TOTAL_BUDGET column (using the example above, **TOTAL_BUDGET** is only **30K**).

This is what i have done so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_budget
           BEFORE INSERT on WorkOn
            FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
       budget number;
BEGIN
        SELECT SUM(Project.Budget) INTO budget
        FROM WorkOn 
        INNER JOIN Project 
        ON WorkOn.P# = Project.P# 
        WHERE E# = :NEW.E#;        

        UPDATE Employee
        SET Total_Budget = budget WHERE E# = :NEW.E#;
   END;
```

I tried changing `BEFORE INSERT` to `AFTER INSERT` but realised i wouldn't be able to do this as i am modifying a mutating table. Is it possible to use row triggers to complete this task?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to add new budget to current sum of budget before updating your employee table :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_budget
           BEFORE INSERT on WorkOn
            FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
       current_total_budget number;
       project_budget number;
BEGIN
        SELECT SUM(Project.Budget) INTO current_total_budget 
        FROM WorkOn 
        INNER JOIN Project 
        ON WorkOn.P# = Project.P# 
        WHERE E# = :NEW.E#;        

        SELECT Project.Budget INTO project_budget
        FROM Project
        WHERE P# = :NEW.P#;

        current_total_budget := current_total_budget + project_budget;

        UPDATE Employee
        SET Total_Budget = current_total_budget WHERE E# = :NEW.E#;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the mutating table error because you're select from the table you're inserting into within the trigger body. You should can achieve what you want using compound triggers. Steven feuerstein has written an excellent [blog](http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2016/12/get-rid-of-mutating-table-trigger.html) explaining how to solve this type of problem using triggers.